# .NET Progress bar in taskbar on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, progress-bar

How can I make my winforms app to show its progress bar in the icon of the taskbar on windows 7?

e.g: chrome with downloads.

Thanks!!

Diego

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to download the [Windows API Code Pack for .NET](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and use those components to interact with Windows 7 (assuming you're not using .NET 4.0).

If you are using .NET 4.0, you should include the [System.Windows.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.aspx) namespace to gain access to the Windows 7 task bar features.

Comment: I've recently noted that my application breaks in some windows which are not Windows 7. Do I have any other option than asking if its Windows 7 before setting the progress state?

Comment: `if (Environment.OsVersion.Major >= 6) { ... }`

Answer (score 10):

In WPF4 you have

```
 <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo> </..>
 </...>
```

Comment: A really good example lives here: http://10rem.net/blog/2009/10/29/showing-progress-in-the-windows-7-taskbar-with-wpf-4-and-a-short-romp-through-windows-7-cleartype-settings

Comment: Great, no need of extra dll with this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Windows® API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). Demo code is available at [Windows 7 Taskbar Dynamic Overlay Icons and Progress Bars](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/07/28/windows-7-taskbar-dynamic-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx)