# Show a progressbar in taskbar while form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, progress-bar, minimized

I wonder how can i accomplish the following:

I would like to display the progress of a progressbar on the taskbar while my window is minimized. See [here](http://www.marcofolio.net/images/stories/useful/reviews/windows_7/progress-bar.png) for a visual description.

See how the icon on the taskbar gradually fills with green color following the main progressbar in the window?

Could someone tell me how to do that?

Update:

I downloaded windows api code pack and referenced it in my project and wrote the following code but nothing happens when i run my app  increment the pbar and minimize:

```
    private void updatepbar()
    { 
        tpb.Value = progressBar1.Value;
    }

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate { updatepbar(); });
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
```

What am i doing wrong?
thanks alot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155003/net-progress-bar-in-taskbar-on-windows-7

Comment: Similiar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295890/windows-7-progress-bar-in-taskbar-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/07/28/windows-7-taskbar-dynamic-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx

```
Taskbar.ProgressBar.State = 
(TaskbarButtonProgressState)Enum.Parse(
        typeof(TaskbarButtonProgressState), 
        (string)comboBoxProgressBarStates.SelectedItem);

if (Taskbar.ProgressBar.State != TaskbarButtonProgressState.Indeterminate)
   Taskbar.ProgressBar.CurrentValue = progressBar1.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only working for Windows7 and you can just easily use the Microsoft-Api.

Explained with a nice example on [WindowsTeamBlog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/07/28/windows-7-taskbar-dynamic-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx) and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a standard progressbar in your main form - Windows 7 will detect it and mimic it on the taskbar automatically:

From http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/07/28/windows-7-taskbar-dynamic-overlay-icons-and-progress-bars.aspx:

> If you already use a standard progress bar in your application’s top
>   level window, the DMW will pick it up and, by default, display its
>   progress as an overlay on top of your application. However, you can
>   programmatically control the progress bar behavior on your
>   application’s icon.

Comment: although this is my case i dont see such effect. i have a progressbar in my main form but when i minimize my app  nothing happens.